# set height of column equal to parent div and responsive in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

[complete row view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ieuEt.jpg)

I have a row with two column inside it, one column has two more rows inside it.  
The height of the column with two rows is more than the other column, set the height of the column with out row equal to height of the column with rows and it should be responsive. I am using **Bootstrap**.  
I have already tried `height:auto,inherit` it did not work.  
Check image for view, i want right side column height same as left side column height

Comment: Upload here that What you tried...so it save the other's time.

Comment: Just add inline style in html ```height:100℅ ! important;``` try doing this to the column which you want to increase the height. It can done with external css file too by adding a class but inline will be a better option

Comment: i have tried setting height values auto and inherit, I also set manually height of div but i have to set it again for every screen, i don't want that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for this you must use display: flex

```
.row{
  display: flex;
}
.row > div{
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/twL6azag/

Comment: Flex is not works in all the devices so keep in mind.

Comment: one more solution  use position: absolute; and set padding to parent = width needed block

Comment: or use js get width of the highest div and set this height to others divs